# placing multiple markers on google map from array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocode

I'm trying to place multiple markers on a map that are provided from an array. Right now only my initial point loads (NYC).

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var markersArray = [];

//plot initial point using geocode instead of coordinates (works just fine)
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     latlang = geocoder.geocode( { 'address': 'New York City'}, function(results, status) { //use latlang to enter city instead of coordinates 
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            markersArray.push(marker);
            }
            else{
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
    var myOptions = {
        center: latlang, zoom: 5, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    };
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);

  }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Everything below this line is for attempting to plot the markers

  var locationsArray = ['Pittsburgh','Chicago', 'Atlanta'];

  function plotMarkers(){
for(var i = 0; i < locationsArray.length; i++){
  codeAddresses(locationsArray[i]);
}
  }

  function codeAddresses(address){
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) { 
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            //markersArray.push(marker); 
            }
            else{
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
  });
  }
```

Comment: you need to provide more information about your problem are you getting some exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not actually calling `plotMarkers` anywhere in the snippet above! When I added into the end of initialize (after map is defined) it works great! http://jsfiddle.net/T5aKE/

```
       ...
         map = new google.maps.Map...
         plotMarkers();
       ...
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed such an obvious mistake. I always seem to require a second set of eyes! Thank you!